# JSONDecodeError when using WHILE loop problems

Tags: python, json

I have this code that retrieves some json. The json gets updated by the system we use, but I dont know when. I need to get that updated json, so I have my code set as follows:

```
    length= int( self.headers['Content-length'] )
    data = json.loads(self.rfile.read( length ).decode('utf-8'))
    order_status = data['order']['order_status']['name']
    print(order_status)

    while order_status == "Awaiting Payment":
        data = json.loads(self.rfile.read( length ).data.decode('utf-8'))         
        print(data)  
        time.sleep(10) # sleep for 10 seconds
```

The error shows up on the data variable inside the loop, but the first data variable works(I get a value for order_status). I call that first data variable so I can check the order_status->name, but why isnt the second data variable working? It should be able to pull the same information as the first one yet I get this error.

```
JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: The data you are parsing is not JSON. It starts with `\x00` which is not allowed.

Comment: if i do a dump on the initial data variable it returns a full json string. The error is on the second one, so whats changing?

Comment: Possibly  the rfile is a stream, there's no bytes left in the stream after the first read.

Comment: if thats the case, how could i compensate for that? Could i start a new stream within the loop? Im quite lost here